# overlaping text with different styles over image, prevent text of one style to be shown on top of the text of another style

Tags: html, css

I know how to place some text over an image, but when that text contains different classes, different text styles, text lines overlap one on top of another.

Here is the simple html code with only one text style that works:

```
<li style="" class="portfolio-content-CV">
    <div class="contentCV"><img src="images/backgr.png" height="500" width="510">
        <p class="auto-style2"><span lang="es">yada yada</span></p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
<li style="" class="portfolio-content-CV">
<div class="contentCV"><img src="images/backgr.png" height="500" width="510">
        <p class="auto-style2"><span lang="es">yada yada</span></p>
        <p class="auto-style1"><span lang="es">bla bla bla</span></p>
    </div>
</li>
```

The css is formated as follows:

```
#portfolio-list .portfolio-content-CV a{
    width: 510px;
    float: left;
    height:500px;
    display:?table;
    border:0.5px solid grey;
}

.contentCV {
    width: 510px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 0px solid #E2E2E2;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.contentCV a.titlesmall {   display: none; }

.auto-style2 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: "AGENCYR";
    font-size: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;   
    top: 6px; 
    left: -8px; 
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
}

.auto-style1{
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-family: "AGENCYR";
    font-size: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;   
    top: 6px; 
    left: -8px; 
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Any idea how can I get a complex text with different text styles to overlap over an image? o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they overlap is because they have the same positioning:

```
top: 6px; 
left: -8px;
```

and absolute positioned elements tend to overlap each other.

So you can create a div wrapper and put the p tags in it:

```
<div class="textWrapper">
   <p class="auto-style2"><span lang="es">yada yada</span></p>
   <p class="auto-style1"><span lang="es">bla bla bla</span></p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.textWrapper{
    position: absolute;   
    top: 6px; 
    left: -8px; 
}
```

Make sure to remove the position absolute from the `<p>` tags